# Is it possible to use "place holder" in values of "yas-choose-value"?

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

In emacs yas-minor-mode, I want to use place-holders in values listed in yas-choose-value.
Is it possible?
Following code is what I want to do.
However it doesn't work well..

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: my_func
# key: my_func
# --
function_${1:$$(yas-choose-value '("x1(arg1=${2:foo}", "arg2=${3:bar)" "x2(arg1=${2:hoge})" "x3()" ))}
$0
```

I expects following operation.

**(step-1)** yas-expand is executed for "my_func"

I should be able to select one from "x1", "x2" and "x3"

**(step-2)** arguments should be changed acording to the selection in (step-1)

- if "x1" is selected,

  ```
  function_x1(arg1=foo, arg2=bar)
  ```

  should be complemented.
  Positions of "foo" and "bar" are place holder and they are default value.
- if "x2" is selected,

  ```
  function_x2(arg1=hoge)
  ```

  should be complemented.
  Positions of "hoge" is place holder and it is default value.
- if "x3" is selected,

  ```
   function_x3()
  ```

  should be complemented. No argument.

Comment: It might be worth considering editing your question to make things a little more clear: what specifically doesn't work well?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I added expected operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has the functionality you are looking for. Give this a shot.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: my_func
# key: my_func
# --
function_`(yas-choose-value '("x1(arg1=${1:foo}, arg2=${2:bar})" "x2(arg1=${1:hoge})" "x3()"))`
$0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your snippets. However, (step-2) doesn't work well in my environment. For instance, if "x2" is selected, I want to edit the place holder ${1:hoge}. But it was treated as normal string and I could not edit it.

Comment: What is your environment? I have emacs 24.5 and yas snippits 0.8.0. Do you get the dialog box as your first step for choosing a function?

Comment: I'm using emacs 24.5.1 and yasnippet 0.91. Yes, I get the dialog
box(as helm interface) for choosing following ones when I type "my_func" and execute "yas-expand".

    x1(arg1=${1:foo}, arg2=${2:bar}) , 
    x2(arg1=${1:hoge}) , 
    x3()

However, after one from them is choosen, it is input as a plain text into a buffer. ${1:foo}, ${2:bar} and ${1:hoge} are not treated as place holders.

Comment: Hmm, there must be some other yas setting that is making it not work for you as it works perfectly with my set set up :/ Wish I could help more than that.